# How to get specific length in multiple class of jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to have a jQuery plugin, that shows me the number of elements there is in each class separately. For example in the following example, my preferred result is:

```
the result is: 4
the result is: 6
```

What I actually get is:

```
the result is: 10
```

How can I do this?

```
<body> 

<div>
  <div class="test"><p>1</p><p>1</p></div>
  <div class="test"><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>   

<script>
(function ( $ ) {
  $.fn.mycount = function() {
    var x = $(this).find('p').length;
    console.log('result is : ' , x * 2);
  };

  $('.test').mycount();

}( jQuery ));   

</script>
```

The main point is that I want to have it in a plugin, and not with each.

Comment: How many first child?

Comment: I want to know exactly how many child there is in any of the classes

Comment: what's wrong with each? I didn't see you are looking for an answer that not use `.each()`.

Comment: I want to use output numbers in another function. my main point is, I have a image slider, and I want to know, how many image there is in each class. In another way, I want a variable called var mycount = (number of images). so this variable should have different value for each class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.fn.mycount = function() {
    var curr = $(this), arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<curr.length; i++)
    {
    var x = curr[i].children().length;
    arr.push(x)
    }
    return arr;
  };
```

Will give you the number of children inside each element in the form of array.

```
var arr = $('.test').mycount();
```

Now use this `arr` in another function.

Comment: It's the same result bro, it gives the count of all children

Comment: it's not giving me, my desired result, this way it just count all the children, in both test class and not consider them separately.

Comment: You said  : my preferd result is: the result is: 4, the result is: 6, what I get:the result is: 10

Comment: @void, you could use `each` iterator instead : ` $(this).each(function(i, element){
  var x = $(element).children().length;
     console.log('result is : ' + x);
 });
`

Comment: @JCSama, OP mentioned in the last line that he does not want to use each.

Comment: You wanted something different? Or this is what you required?

Comment: I want to use output numbers in another function. my main point is, I have a image slider, and I want to know, how many image there is in each class. In another way, I want a variable called var mycount = (number of images). so this variable should have different value for each class.

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/6h590e9s/2/)

```
$.fn.mycount = function() {
    var curr = $(this);
    for(var i=0; i<curr.length; i++){
        var x = $(curr[i]).find('p').length;
        console.log('result is : ' + x*2);
    }
};

$('.test').mycount();
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but I mentioned in my question that I don't want to have it with each.

Comment: yes I noticed it when I looked at the comments... sorry

Comment: I updated my answer to get rid of the each function.

Comment: Sorry bro, I think, my question has not enough clarification, 
I want to use output numbers in another function. my main point is, I have a image slider, and I want to know, how many image there is in each class. In another way, I want a variable called var mycount = (number of images). so this variable should have different value for each class.